# Writing data and ignoring duplicates.

Tags: php, api, foursquare

I am currently working with the foursquare API. Each time I run the following PHP script, it takes the most recent checkin displayed on the users profile and writes it to a text file. Each entry to the text file is separated by a comma.

My problem is, I could run the PHP file 5 times a minute and it would fetch the same checkin that it has already fetched. What I would like to do is make it so the php script below reads the most recent checkin of the user that is displayed in the foursquare JSON and if it is something that has already been aggregated in the text file in the entry before this one, it would ignore it and not add in into the text file.

```
<?php 
$charlotte = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/5464313?oauth_token=2ZO1PQOUAD5SXRAJOLZVH53RBQ1EB2C23FE2GUZLJYQUJ3SY&v=20121123"));
$venuename = $charlotte->response->user->checkins->items[0]->venue->name;
$file = 'charlotte.txt';
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current .= $venuename.',';
file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>

<?php

$arran = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/1050511?oauth_token=2ZO1PQOUAD5SXRAJOLZVH53RBQ1EB2C23FE2GUZLJYQUJ3SY&v=20121109"));
$venuename = $arran->response->user->checkins->items[0]->venue->name;
$file = 'arran.txt';
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current .= $venuename.',';
file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

What the text file for each user looks like, when the PHP script has run and entered the name of the most recent checkin.

```
Venue Name, Venue Name, Venue Name, Venue Name
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I assume Foursquare returns an ID for each checkin. When looping over the API results, you could just check if the ID matches the last ID in your text file and if not, assume it’s a new checkin, and write it to the file.

Comment: Any ideas where I would start with that Martin? Very new to PHP (the above is the most PHP I've ever written). Thanks so much for your speedy response!